# Can I filter table row content but ignore one element?

Tags: html, jquery, filter, row, toggle

I want to filter this table's rows on content in every  except for what's inside the . Is it possible?

With this script, if I search for "John", I want to return only the row with *john@example.com*. I want to ignore the the  that contains *"john"*.

I can't seem to make it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).not('.demolist').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com
        <div class='demolist'>john</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 1. if you remove the toLowerCase from `not('.demolist').text().toLowerCase()` you will only find john 2. But since it is the same row as John, you do not gain anything

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, but they're not in the same row. I edited the question so case was the same in both rows..

Comment: did you suceed at the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's another way to this, but I got using the function `$(this).detach()` for the divs with class "demolist" to remove from the DOM, then the search doesn't reach there. But to put it in the DOM again you have to tell where (by id or class), so I create another DIV beteween the "demolist" called "append" to use the function `$(this).append(elem[index])` . I used jQuery each to list all elements in the class. Like this:

HTML

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com<div class="append">    
      <div class='demolist'>Mary</div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com<div class="append">    
      <div class='demolist'>John</div></div> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var elem = $(".demolist");
    var ap = $(".append");
    elem.each(function(index, el) {
        $(this).detach();
    });
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1); 
    });
    ap.each(function(index, el) {
        $(this).append(elem[index]);
    });
  });
});
```

You can see the working example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cm3ns1wx/

Comment: Genius. It didn't occur to me to remove the element completely, perform the search and re-attach. Thank you!